# Problems with onchange event

Tags: javascript

JSFiddle:  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QkK26/)

I have problems with `onchange`. I've written both of them the same way, but only one works correctly. My function named `changerImage` works fine; it's `changerLogo` that doesn't want to do anything.

These two functions are pretty much the same, so why isn't it working?

```
function changerLogo() {
    var indice2 = lstLogos.selectedIndex;
    var choix2 = lstLogos.options[indice2].value;
    grosseImage2.src = "images/logo/" + choix2;
}
```

Comment: What is lstLogos, what is grosseImage2? Also define "not working" - are you getting an error, or is it just not doing anything?

Comment: my function chagerLogos doesnt do anything. lstLogos and grosseImage2 are my ID in the html page.

Comment: Neither image updates for me.

Comment: How is changerLogo bound?

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't work at all, because you didn't change the wrapping settings. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/QkK26/2/

Comment: How did `1stLogos` become `ElementById("1stLogos")?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Browsers :P (And it's `lstLogos`, not `1stLogos`. Valid identifier.)

Comment: Syntax error. Closing as too localised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `onchange` as `onchage` in `onload`:

```
lstLogos.onchage = changerLogo;
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkK26/3/) (not that the images work there...)

Comment: Thank you man! :) I fell stupid now...

Comment: You should mark @minitech's answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the typo minitech pointed out, use addEventListener:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Or just use a library like jQuery `$('#1stLogos').change(function ..` which will do the heavy  event listening lifting for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/E7Qvg/

```
document.getElementById('lstLogos').addEventListener('change', changerLogo);
document.getElementById('lstPhotos').addEventListener('change', changerImage);


function changerImage() {
    var indice1 = lstPhotos.selectedIndex;
    var choix1 = lstPhotos.options[indice1].value;
    grosseImage1.src = "images/circuit/" + choix1;
    alert('changerImage works: ' + choix1);
} 

function changerLogo() {
    var indice2 = lstLogos.selectedIndex;
    var choix2 = lstLogos.options[indice2].value;
    alert('changerLogo works: ' + choix2);
}
```

Comment: Why use `addEventListener`? It doesn't seem likely that any other event listener will need to be added to this, and it saves a library/compatibility problems/complexity to just use the simple ones when possible.

Comment: Is that what you do? Use on* events until you need to add additional event listeners to an object? If a library is being used, the asker should use what that library makes available.

Comment: Does it look like a library's being used to you? :) But yes. Yes, that's exactly what I do. (Depending on what kind of browser support I need.)

Comment: Then why bring libraries up at all? I've avoided on* event listeners since the days I stopped putting JavaScript in HTML attributes.

Comment: I brought it up because at the very beginning of your answer, you say "use `addEventListener`" without actually saying why. And... you still haven't. (Oh, libraries. Because of the "Or just use a library like jQuery" part. jQuery wasn't part of the project.)

Comment: True, but I added a link to MDN. Adding handlers directly on the attributes of elements is a poor way to manage events. It lets you only add one, it can lead to memory leaks, and the other reasons listed on the MDN page. Seems strange to me that someone would contest this.

Comment: What memory leaks? If you mean the "Memory issues" section... it uses and applies to `addEventListener`, too. All MDN has to say on the subject of `on*` is: "Because it was essentially part of DOM 0, this method is very widely supported and requires no special cross–browser code; hence it is normally used to register event listeners dynamically unless the extra features of `addEventListener()` are needed."

Comment: I'm speaking about circular references where the function on the element's attribute has a reference to the element.   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/

Comment: So that just happens with `on*` elements? Haha, wow, that's really bad. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: I see what you mean about compatibility issues. I forgot about IE8 not supporting this. Good point.